# Spooling a small file is taking a huge time

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-processing, spool

Hi I am trying to spool some data into a text file using a batch file.

The SQL file is something like below -

```
set termout off
set echo off
set feed off
set pagesize 0
set linesize 300
set recsep off

spool %DATADIR%\qptBIFPReps.txt;

set heading off;

<<Query>>

spool off;
exit;
```

This query while running it in TOAD is returning around 28000 rows within around 2-3 minutes.

Whereas spooling this file is taking around 3.5 hours.

Can someone suggest how I can speedup the spooling process.

Any help is appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: Spooling can't be taking time. Did you try running the query in command prompt manually. I assume, the query mentioned in file is different or missing something. So the selection itself is taking time.

Comment: Yup, The query is absolutely fine. Though I forgot to mention that I am delimiting the rows.

Comment: Did you see the progress in file contents during the time? Was it increasing slowly?

Comment: Yup... very slowly... In fact it was writing around 500 line in around 4-5 minutes.

Comment: Then there could be delay in the File I/O at OS level... A simple restart will kill unwanted idle processes.. etc.. Just a guess.